# How can I omit one character in the regular expression

Tags: jmeter

I need to omit one character in the regular expression extractor. Any idea how we can tackle that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJnOg.png)

Actual output in regular expression => Match[1][1]=D113NS/23
Expected Result : D113NS/23 (No need of one slash).

Tried different combination of regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

1. [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) hence using regular expressions for extracting data from JSON is not the best idea. It worth considering using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) instead. The relevant [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression would be something like `$..model_code`
2. If the backslash is in the response and hence in the variable and you need to remove it from there you can use either [__strReplace()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) function or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function for this.